# Forcing images to be the same shape but still keeping them responsive

Tags: css

I'm using a template for a weekly newsletter and I'm trying to keep all the images that get piped in to the newsletter to be the same size.  Here's the current code:

```
<img src="xxx {{ content.thumbnail_uri }}" width="340" 
style="margin: 0; 
color: #222222; 
font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; 
font-weight: normal; 
line-height: 19px; 
padding: 0; 
text-align: left; 
font-size: 14px; 
margin-bottom: 0; 
width: 100%; 
height: auto; 
max-width: 340px;" />
```

The problem is that when the template gets generated there is an introduction that pushes down the left column and the image height on that size gets squished down.  Is there a way that I can guarantee that the images stay the same height and width while still keeping it responsive for mobile?

Comment: You mean `object-fit: cover;` ?

Comment: @AlonEitan Yeah that might be exactly what I'm looking for.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do something like this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<style>
    html, body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        height: 100%;
    }
    * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .image-holder {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
        grid-gap: 1rem;
    }
    .image-holder img {
        width: 100%;
    }
</style>
<body>
    <div class="image-holder">
        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/10/30/16/06/water-lily-3784022__340.jpg"  alt="image1"/>
        <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/colorful-flower-on-dark-tropical-260nw-721703848.jpg"  alt="image2"/>
        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/05/28/22/11/message-in-a-bottle-3437294__340.jpg"  alt="image2"/>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Danilo, I'll see if I can make it work!  Is there any possible solution that you can think of that keeps all the code inline to the image or will wrapping be required?

Comment: I can't think something without wrapping, sorry :(

Comment: I think that you can remove it, but it's up to you. Maybe you'll need something, but probably you can remove most of it

Comment: Hey, it was working when previewing the newsletter but when it actually gets sent out as an email and rendered the images are gigantic.  Any thoughts on why that might be?

Comment: That's strange, maybe the e-mail tools doesn't support css grid. But I'm not sure.